# Pyside populate QTreeView with list

Tags: python, list, pyside, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

i searched for some time now and i can not find an satisfactory answer to my problem. I need to represent a list in a QTreeView:

Example:

```
['.', ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']], ['A', ['G', 'H']], ['A\\G', []], ['A\\H', ['K', 'L']], ['A\\G\\K', []], ['A\\G\\L', []], ['B', ['I', 'J']], ['B\\I', []], ['B\\J', []], ['C', []], ['D', []], ['E', []], ['F', ['M']], ['F\\M', []]
```

Should be represented like so:

```
.
|____A
     |____H
     |____G
          |____K
          |____L
|____B
     |____I
     |____J
|____C
|____D
|____E
|____F
     |____M
```

EDIT: Maybe the data is prepared badly. I could also go for this kind of structure:

```
[".", "A", "A\\G", "A\\H", "A\\H\\K", "A\\H\\L", "B", "B\\I", "B\\J", "C", "D", "E", "F", "F\\M"]
```

It is not a problem to visualize that structure in the console but i wont get it right for the treeview.
This is my Node Class and my TreeModel

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys


class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name, parent=None):
        self._name = name
        self._children = []
        self._parent = parent

        if parent is not None:
            parent.add_child(self)

    def type_info(self):
        return 'NODE'

    def add_child(self, child):
        self._children.append(child)

    def insert_child(self, position, child):
        if position < 0 or position > len(self._children):
            return False

        self._children.insert(position, child)
        child._parent = self
        return True

    def remove_child(self, position):
        if position < 0 or position > len(self._children):
            return False

        child = self._children.pop(position)
        child._parent = None
        return True

    def name(self):
        return self._name

    def set_name(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def child(self, row):
        return self._children[row]

    def child_count(self):
        return len(self._children)

    def parent(self):
        return self._parent

    def row(self):
        if self._parent is not None:
            return self._parent._children.index(self)

    def log(self, tab_level=-1):
        output = ''
        tab_level += 1

        for i in range(tab_level):
            output += '\t'

        output += '|____' + self._name + '\n'

        for child in self._children:
            output += child.log(tab_level)

        tab_level -= 1

        return output

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.log()


class TemplateTreeModel(QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, root, parent=None):
        super(TemplateTreeModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._root_node = root

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        if not parent.isValid():
            parent_node = self._root_node
        else:
            parent_node = parent.internalPointer()

        return parent_node.child_count()

    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 1

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid():
            print('root')
            return None

        node = index.internalPointer()

        if role == Qt.DisplayRole or role == Qt.EditRole:
            if index.column() == 0:
                return node.name()

        if role == Qt.DecorationRole:
            if index.column() == 0:
                type_info = node.type_info()

                if type_info == 'FOLDER':
                    return QIcon('src/dir.png')

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if index.isValid():
            if role == Qt.EditRole:
                node = index.internalPointer()
                node.set_name(value)

                return True
        return False

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if section == 0:
                return 'Templates'
            else:
                return 'Type'

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def parent(self, index):
        node = self.get_node(index)
        parent_node = node.parent()

        if parent_node == self._root_node:
            return QModelIndex()

        return self.createIndex(parent_node.row(), 0, parent_node)

    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        parent_node = self.get_node(parent)

        child_item = parent_node.child(row)

        if child_item:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, child_item)
        else:
            return QModelIndex

    def get_node(self, index):
        if index.isValid():
            node = index.internalPointer()
            if node:
                return node
        return self._root_node

    def insertRows(self, position, rows, parent=QModelIndex()):
        parent_node = self.get_node(parent)
        self.beginInsertRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1)

        for row in range(rows):
            child_count = parent_node.child_count()
            child_node = Node('untitled' + str(child_count))
            success = parent_node.insert_child(position, child_node)

        self.endInsertRows()

        return success

    def removeRows(self, position, rows, parent=QModelIndex()):
        parent_node = self.get_node(parent)
        self.beginRemoveRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1)

        for row in range(rows):
            success = parent_node.remove_child(position)

        self.endRemoveRows()

        return success
```

Any idea how to do this properly?

```
    for root, dirs in structure_list:
        depth = root.split(os.sep)
        print((len(depth) - 1) * '---', os.path.basename(root))
```

This is how i would do it for console visualization. roughly ;)
Thx!

Comment: ah dammit ;) just a subclass of the Node Class i forgot to edit out ;)
Ty for the feedback. Its edited

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all your model is implemented incorrectly in certain parts, for example the root is an invisible element so we must add it, etc, so I have modified your code plus I have added certain methods that I show below:

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, name="", parent=None):
        self._parent = parent
        self._name = name
        self._children = []

    def children(self):
        return self._children

    def hasChildren(self):
        return bool(self.children())

    def parent(self):
        return self._parent

    def name(self):
        return self._name

    def set_name(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def type_info(self):
        return 'NODE'

    def columnCount(self):
        return 1

    def child_count(self):
        return len(self._children)

    def add_child(self, child):
        self._children.append(child)
        child._parent = self

    def insert_child(self, position, child):
        if 0 <= position < child_count:
            self._children.insert(position, child)
            child._parent = self
            return True
        return False

    def remove_child(self, position):
        if 0 <= position < len(self._children):
            child = self._children.pop(position)
            child._parent = None
            return True
        return False

    def child(self, row):
        if 0 <= row < self.child_count():
            return self._children[row]

    def row(self):
        if self._parent is not None:
            return self._parent._children.index(self)
        return -1

    def find_child_by_name(self, name):
        for child in self._children:
            if child.name() == name:
                return child
        return None

    def log(self, tab_level=-1):
        output = ''
        tab_level += 1

        for i in range(tab_level):
            output += '\t'

        output += '|____' + self._name + '\n'

        for child in self._children:
            output += child.log(tab_level)

        tab_level -= 1

        return output

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.log()


class TemplateTreeModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._root_node = Node()

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if section == 0:
                return 'Templates'
            else:
                return 'Type'

    def index(self, row, column, parent):
        if not self.hasIndex(row, column, parent):
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        node = parent.internalPointer() if parent.isValid() else self._root_node
        if node.children:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, node.child(row))
        else:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def parent(self, child):
        if not child.isValid():
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        node = child.internalPointer()
        if node.row() >= 0:
            return self.createIndex(node.row(), 0, node.parent())
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        node = parent.internalPointer() if parent.isValid() else self._root_node
        return node.child_count()

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        return 1

    def hasChildren(self, parent= QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        node = parent.internalPointer() if parent.isValid() else self._root_node
        return node.hasChildren()

    def data(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if index.isValid() and role in (QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, QtCore.Qt.EditRole, ):
            node = index.internalPointer()
            print(node)
            return node.name()

    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if role in (QtCore.Qt.EditRole,):
            node = index.internalPointer()
            node.set_name(value)
            self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)
            return True
        return False

    def flags(self, index: QtCore.QModelIndex):
        return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def indexFromItem(self, it):
        root_index = QtCore.QModelIndex()
        if isinstance(it, Node):
            parents = []
            while it is not self._root_node:
                parents.append(it)
                it = it.parent()
            root = self._root_node
            for parent in reversed(parents):
                root = root.find_child_by_name(parent.name())
                root_index =self.index(root.row(), 0, root_index)
        return root_index

    def item_from_path(self, path, sep):
        depth = path.split(sep)
        root = self._root_node
        for d in depth:
            root = root.find_child_by_name(d)
            if root is None: return None
        return root

    def appendRow(self, item, parent=None):
        self.appendRows([item], parent)

    def appendRows(self, items, parent=None):
        if isinstance(items, list):
            ix = self.indexFromItem(parent)
            self.insertRows(self.rowCount(ix), items, parent)

    def insertRows(self, position, items, parent=None):
        parent_index = self.indexFromItem(parent)
        self.beginInsertRows(parent_index, position, position + len(items) - 1)
        if parent is None:
            parent = self._root_node
        for item in items:
            parent.add_child(item)
        self.endInsertRows()
```

On the other hand in your initial list the pattern is not fulfilled correctly since the roots should start with `.\\` so it must be added when necessary.

```
structure_list = ['.', ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']], ['A', ['G', 'H']], ['A\\G', []], ['A\\H', ['K', 'L']], ['A\\G\\K', []], ['A\\G\\L', []], ['B', ['I', 'J']], ['B\\I', []], ['B\\J', []], ['C', []], ['D', []], ['E', []], ['F', ['M']], ['F\\M', []]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtGui.QTreeView()
    model = TemplateTreeModel()
    w.setModel(model)
    model.appendRow(Node("."))

    for root, dirs in structure_list:
        depth = root.split(os.sep)
        if not root.startswith("."):
            # append .\\,
            # by example if root is "A\\G" then the results is:
            # ".\\A\\G"
            root = "." + os.sep + root
        it = model.item_from_path(root, os.sep)
        model.appendRows([Node(_dir) for _dir in dirs], it)
    w.expandAll()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: You are the man!!! Very much appreciated. You even enhanced my work ;)
this line: model.appendRows([Node(_dir) for _dir in dirs], it)
was really the one thing that made me band my head against the wall ^^

Comment: Just a small question. if i want to change the shown label of the root, how do i do that properly. Just altering model.appendRow(Node(".")) to model.appendRow(Node("ROOT")) does not work...it changes the Name but the structure breaks as well

Comment: change `structure_list = ['.',` ---> `structure_list = ['ROOT',`, and `root.startswith(".")` ---> `root.startswith("ROOT")`, and `model.appendRow(Node("."))` ---> `model.appendRow(Node("ROOT"))`, and `root = "." + os.sep + root` ----> `root = "ROOT" + os.sep + root`. I recommend you take the time and analyze my logic

Comment: I see, that is all connected. Didnt see it through yet, still learning. I will analyze the logic very thoroughly...already learned a thing or two by reading your improvements ;) thx mate

Comment: @zwusel Well, keep doing it, refine the code so you understand the whole logic, do not explain it in my question because it would take too much time.

Comment: I didn't review all of the methods, but at least the ```TemplateTreeModel.parent()``` is incorrect. The first argument of the ```self.createIndex()``` should be the index of the parent node, not the index of the child node.